# Not sending the proper object data to Pusher

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

I dont know why the `name` is not included when broadcasting the event. But it is included in the `return $message`

Here is my Laravel's `MessageController`.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Message;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Events\Chat;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request){
        $message = new Message;
        $message->channel = $request->channel_id;
        $message->by = Auth::user()->id;
        $message->body = $request->message;

        $message->save();
        $message->name = "Clyde Santiago"; //This it the inserted data to the object
        event(new Chat($message)); //sends `message` object to Pusher but not including the `name`
        return $message //returns `message` object including the `name`
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the `$message->name` property actually exist on the object?

Comment: No, it is not. I just want to append the $message->name = "Clyde Santiago"  to the $message. It returns what I expected when accessing it via javascript. But in event(new Chat($message)). The $message->name = "Clyde Santiago"  is not appended

Comment: Yeah, you need to do a bit of reading about OOP PHP. You can't do that.